# MOXy JAXB: how to use BigDecimalAdapter with different precisions

Tags: jaxb, eclipselink, moxy

I have a BigDecimalAdapter to format all BigDecimal types of my model. The declaration in the package-info file is:

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapters({@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value=BigDecimalAdapter.class,type=BigDecimal.class)})
```

My problem is that I must format several BigDecimal with different precissions.

For example, I have two objects:

```
public class Invoice {

    @XmlPath("InvoiceTotals/InvoiceTotal/text()")
    private BigDecimal invoiceTotal;
}
```

and

```
public class Discount {

    @XmlPath("DiscountAmount/text()")
    private BigDecimal discountAmount;

}
```

Now, if the values are:

```
invoice.invoiceTotal = 10.000000000;
discount.discountAmount = 25.00000000;
```

how can I get next results in the final XML?

```
<invoiceTotal>10.00<invoiceTotal/>
<discountAmount>25.0000<discountAmount/>
```

I mean, 2 decimals in the first case and 4 decimals in the second.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to introduce an `XmlAdapter` for each of the representations of `BigDecimal`.  Then instead of registering the `XmlAdapter` at the package level you will need to register them at the property level.  Below is an example.

**Invoice**

```
public class Invoice {

    @XmlPath("InvoiceTotals/InvoiceTotal/text()")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value=BigDecimalTwoPlacesAdapter.class)
    private BigDecimal invoiceTotal;
}
```

**Discount**

```
public class Discount {

    @XmlPath("DiscountAmount/text()")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value=BigDecimalFourPlacesAdapter.class)
    private BigDecimal discountAmount;

}
```